# File read not interpreting Environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

When I try to read a file which contains a environment variable HOSTNAME. 
It is not interpreting its value while reading the file.

For example, if my hostname is **linux1.com**. 
When I try to read a sample file(Test.txt) below

```
/var/log/$HOSTNAME
```

using the code below

```
while read line
do
ls -l $line
done < Test.txt
```

I am expecting it to interpet the $HOSTNAME variable and print it. But it is not working. It is directly doing `ls -l /var/log/$HOSTNAME`, instead of

```
ls -l /var/log/linux1.com
```

The same command is intrepreting the hostname when I run this command in shell.

Any leads on this is highly appreicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Parameter expansion is not recursive. When `$line` is expanded, its value is subject to pathname expansion (globbing) and word-splitting, but not further parameter expansions.